# Decryption of date from file using AES returning random characters

Tags: c#, datetime, encryption, aes

I am reading an encrypted date from a file using AES, and on decryption the string returned is the following : ���C l&|�=O����3 AM

I have read some things but still dont understand what is happening.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
  public static AesCryptoServiceProvider provider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider()
        {
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey),
            IV = new byte[] { 4,  10, 221, 22, 71, 129, 95, 231, 229, 174, 247, 119, 241, 156, 249, 57 },
            BlockSize = 128,
        };

        public static string FIPSEncryptDecrypt(string cipherText, bool Encrypt)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Encrypt)
                {
                    byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cipherText);
                    ICryptoTransform cTransform = provider.CreateEncryptor(provider.Key, provider.IV);
                    byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
                }
                else
                {
                    byte[] toDecryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
                    ICryptoTransform cTransform = provider.CreateDecryptor(provider.Key, provider.IV);
                    byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toDecryptArray, 0, toDecryptArray.Length);
                    return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your question is missing key info. Please edit it and mention what type of file you are decrypting (text, binary, etc), give a sample of the date from that file, and give the code that is used to decrypt the date into a variable (we need to see what type of variable you're using, `DateTime` or `String`). Also it is good to provide the code that you use to display the date on the page because it could be a wrong encoding issue.

Comment: I'd assume there's something going wrong in your conversion to/from a byte array. There's a working example on that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Side note: the `FIPSEncryptDecrypt()` function violates design principles. Consider splitting it to two functions `FIPSEncrypt()` and `FIPSDecrypt()`, or probably better just `Encrypt()` and `Decrypt()`.

Comment: Works for me.  You must provide more information about the inputs, outputs, and calling code to receive help.